# Use original jar when "jnlp.versionEnabled" is set to "true" in JNLP file

Tags: java, apache, swing, maven, jnlp

We recently moved an old java swing application to Maven, and as this application is loaded via JNLP we decided to use versioned jars inside the .jnlp file to meet maven standards. Maven generates automatically the .jnlp file (via a .vm template).

The .jnlp file now looks like this :

```
<jar href="foo-1.0.0.jar" version="1.0.0"/>
<jar href="bar-2.0.0.jar" version="2.0.0"/>
<property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
```

This works fine, but the "foo" and "bar" jars are loaded via apache, and the following errors are now present :

```
[error] File does not exist: path/to/foo-1.0.0__V1.0.0.jar
[error] File does not exist: path/to/bar-2.0.0__V2.0.0.jar
```

Indeed, those files do not exist because they are named "foo-1.0.0.jar" and "bar-2.0.0.jar".

In the access logs we have this :

```
"GET /test/foo-1.0.0__V1.0.0.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 1028
"GET /test/foo-1.0.0.jar?version-id=1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 279425
```

Those logs are in accordance with the javadoc : "(...)if the JAR version is specified, the server is checked for the versioned JAR (...). The original jar will be used if the versioned jar file is not found."

As far of now the only solution would be to change maven configuration to generate the .jnlp file and the jars physical names according to the naming rules, but that would be time consuming and I don't know if that's even possible.

Is there a way to force Java to load only the original jar ?

Comment: Is this bad?  It just means that Web Start is checking for a [JnlpDownloadServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) that serves a .jar file that exactly matches the requested version.  (The *app*-*version*.jar naming scheme is a Maven invention;  normally, object-oriented .jar files shouldn't have a version number in their names, since successive versions should adhere to all previous contracts.)

Comment: It's not a major issue, however our sys admins are angry (:D) because there're too many errors in the logs. The error logs are the main issue here.